# Сериализация в C# объектов, имеющих взаимные ссылки

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация, десериализация, serializable

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сериализовывать/десериализовывать объекты в XML, имеющие взаимные ссылки.
Например, есть классы `Car` и `Garage`. `Garage` содержит список объектов типа `Car`, при этом каждый объект `Car` имеет ссылку на объект типа `Garage`.
Вот класс `Garage`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CarsApp
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Garage
    {
        public List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();

        public Garage() { }

        public void AddCar(Car car)
        {
            cars.Add(car);
            car.Garage = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот класс `Car`:

```
using System;

namespace CarsApp
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Car
    {
        public string Model { get; set; } 
        public Garage Garage { get; set; }

        public Car() { }

        public Car(string model)
        {
            Model = model;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот код сериализации объекта типа `Garage`:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace CarsApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car fiat = new Car("Fiat");
            Car reno = new Car("Reno");
            Garage garage = new Garage();
            garage.AddCar(fiat);
            garage.AddCar(reno);

            XmlSerializer xmlFormat = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Garage));
            using(Stream fStream = new FileStream("garage.xml", 
                FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                xmlFormat.Serialize(fStream, garage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В результате выполнения получаю ошибку

> `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Ошибка при создании документа XML.'`
>   `InnerException
>   System.InvalidOperationException: При сериализации объекта типа CarsApp.Garage обнаружена циклическая ссылка.`

В чём ошибка и как исправить?

Comment: А как вы их потом обратно десериализовать хотите? Как вообще ваш xml на выходе должен выглядеть?

Comment: @tym32167 а где указано что это должен быть xml обязательно окроме кода? Скорее всего, ему и бинари форматтер подойдет.

Comment: @Andrew в смысле где? Это же в тексте вопроса написано, в колонне и в ошибке.

Comment: @tym32167 то что он пытается сделать это через XML  не значит что ему это нужно обязательно делать через XML.  В ошибке написано потому, что он пытался реализовать через XML. Сам же вопрос не звучит как "как сериализовать в XML.... ?", сам вопрос звучит как "как правильно сериализовывать/десериализовывать объекты, имеющие взаимные ссылки?". Ему, скорее всего, плевать, во что будет сериализованы обьекты

Comment: @Andrew может да, может нет. Вы сейчас гаданием занимаетесь. Хотите знать наверняка - спросите у автора.

Comment: @Andrew формат взял по заданию преподавателя, хотя может быть я его неправильно понял, когда спрашивал про возникшую проблему сериализации. Он рекомендовал почитать про атрибуты и dto, а ещё гуглить xmlIgnore. Пока ничего внятного не нагуглилось. И да, я действительно не представляю, как в xml должна выглядеть сериализация в случае цикличности ссылок.

Comment: подправил вопрос и тэги

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этой цели можно использовать [DataContractSerializer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2) с настройкой [DataContractSerializerSettings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializersettings?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Добавьте к проекту сборку System.Runtime.Serialization.dll и откройте пространство имен System.Runtime.Serialization.

```
var dcss = new DataContractSerializerSettings { PreserveObjectReferences = true };

var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Garage), dcss);

using (Stream fStream = new FileStream("test.xml",
    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    dcs.WriteObject(fStream, garage);
}
```

`PreserveObjectReferences = true` как раз будет сохранять ссылки на объекты. Циклические ссылки разруливаются корректно.

При чтении можно создавать сериализатор без указания настроек.

PS: аттрибут `Serializable` не нужен для xml-сериализаторов. Его использует `BinaryFormatter`. Кстати, этот форматтер тоже корректно обрабатывает циклические ссылки - можно использовать его.

PPS: при наличии атрибута `Serializable` у класса `Car` генерируется xml следующего вида:

```
<Car z:Id="3">
  <_x003C_Garage_x003E_k__BackingField z:Ref="1" i:nil="true"/>
  <_x003C_Model_x003E_k__BackingField z:Id="4">Fiat</_x003C_Model_x003E_k__BackingField>
</Car>
```

Без этого атрибута xml выглядит намного приятней:

```
<Car z:Id="3">
  <Garage z:Ref="1" i:nil="true"/>
  <Model z:Id="4">Fiat</Model>
</Car>
```

То есть `DataContractSerializer` все-таки как-то учитывает этот атрибут.

Comment: Почему-то не компилируется. Выдаёт ошибку                                                                                                                           `The type or namespace name 'DataContractSerializerSettings' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @golubtsoff, перейдите по ссылке на класс в msdn, там указано в какой сборке и в каком пространстве имён он находится

Comment: @АндрейNOP переходил, разумеется. Прописывал `using System.Runtime.Serialization`, но почему-то не подхватывает этот namespace (отображается серым цветом в Visual Studio). Использую `Visual Studio Community 2017` последнего апдейта, `.Net Framework 4.7.2`.

Comment: @golubtsoff - обновил ответ. Добавьте к проекту сборку `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в References проекта нажал ПКМ и выбрал Add Reference; в открывшемся окне перешёл в Assemblies и в списке выбрал `System.Runtime.Serialization`; нажал ОК - и всё заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать бинарную сериализацию вместо сериализации в XML то можно хранить любые данные лобой сложности вложенности

К классу который будем сериализовать добавляем

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeItem
{}
```

Враппер на сериализацию:

```
public static class Serializator
{
    private static BinaryFormatter _bin = new BinaryFormatter();

    public static void Serialize(string pathOrFileName, object objToSerialise)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(pathOrFileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            try 
            {
                _bin.Serialize(stream, objToSerialise);
            }
            catch (SerializationException e) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string pathOrFileName) 
    {
        T items;

        using (Stream stream = File.Open(pathOrFileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            try 
            {
                items = (T) _bin.Deserialize(stream);
            }
            catch (SerializationException e) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

        return items;
    }
}
```

ну и, собственно, сам пример использования:

```
List<SomeItem> itemsCollected;//list with some data

Serializator.Serialize("data.dat", itemsCollected);

var a = Serializator.Deserialize<List<SomeItem>>("data.dat");
```

В случае ошибки будет выдавать в консоль сообщение о исключении сериализации.