# Как считать много элементов при десериализации если заносим по одному элементу?

Tags: c#, filestream

Столкнулась с проблемой, что после занесения одного значения с помощью сериализации в бинарный файл стало невозможно считать массив структур с бинарного файла дисереализацией целиком, а только можно считать один элемент из бинарника.

Сериализуемая структура:

```
[Serializable]public struct UserInfo
    {
        public string Fio;
        public string Login;
        public string EncodedPassword;
        public string Key;

    }
```

Метод занесения в файл структуры:

```
 public static DBErrorHandler DBSave(UserInfo file)
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            
            var result = DBSearch(file.Login);

            result.Status = 0;
            if (result.Status == 0)
            {

                FileStream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(filename);
                formatter.Serialize(outputStream, file);
                outputStream.Close();

            }
            else
            {
                result.Exception = "Login already exists";
            }

            return result;

        }
```

Метод открытия файла:

```
 private static UserInfo[] DBOpen()
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(filename);
            UserInfo[] DB = (UserInfo[])formatter.Deserialize(inputStream); // выводит ошибку
            inputStream.Close();
            return DB;
        }
```

Ошибка:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'WpfApp1.UserInfo' to type 'WpfApp1.UserInfo[]'.'

При изменении  `UserInfo[] DB = (UserInfo[])formatter.Deserialize(inputStream);`
на `UserInfo DB = (UserInfo)formatter.Deserialize(inputStream)` ошибка исчезает, однако при данном коде становится невозможно считать значения дальше первого элемента.

Comment: по моему, ошибка возникает из за того, что при сериализации массива элементов он сериализуется не как "набор айтемов",  а именно как array - а при добавлении элемента эта структура ломается

Comment: `FileStream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(filename);` вы пишете в конец файла или перезаписываете файл каждый раз?

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что если записать несколько желементов в файл друг за другом, то получится считать их как массив?

Comment: Здесь есть решение твоей проблемы и с более элегантным кодом. А так же пример сериализации листа. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/931105/186752